# Vanilla Javascript blur event not activating when clicking out of textbox

Tags: javascript

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            const list = document.querySelector('.output ul');
            const searchInput = document.querySelector('.output input');
            const searchBtn = document.querySelector('.output button');
            const historyDiv = document.querySelector('.output .search');

            list.innerHTML = '';

            let myHistory = [];

            historyDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";

            function addToHistory() {
                // we will only allow a term to be entered if the search input isn't empty
                console.log("button click");
                if (searchInput.value !== '') {
                    // number 1
                    myHistory.push(searchInput.value);
                    console.log(`${searchInput.value} added to history`);
                    // empty the list so that we don't display duplicate entries
                    // the display is regenerated every time a search term is entered.
                    list.innerHTML = '';

                    // loop through the array, and display all the search terms in the list
                    for (let i = 0; i < myHistory.length; i++) {
                        itemText = myHistory[i];
                        const listItem = document.createElement('li');
                        listItem.textContent = itemText;
                        list.appendChild(listItem);
                    }

                    // If the array length is 5 or more, remove the oldest search term
                    if (myHistory.length >= 5) {
                    // number 2
                        myHistory.shift();
                    }

                    // empty the search input and focus it, ready for the next term to be entered
                    searchInput.value = '';
                    searchInput.focus();
                }
            }
            
            searchBtn.addEventListener('click', addToHistory);
            searchInput.addEventListener('focus', function() {
                console.log("Focussed");

                if (myHistory.length > 0) {
                    historyDiv.style.visibility = "visible";
                }
            });
            searchBtn.addEventListener('blur', function() {
                console.log("Blurr");
                historyDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
            });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>

    <body>


        <div class="output" style="min-height: 150px;">

            <input type="text"><button style="margin-bottom: 3em;" >Search</button>
            
            <br>

            <div class="search">
                <span>Your recent search terms:</span>
                <ul></ul>
            </div>
            
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

When the user clicks the input field, it should trigger the focus listener, displaying the history list.

When they click out anywhere on the page, it should trigger the blur listener, hiding the history list.

The blur function mysteriously doesn't function like this, and I do not know why. It focuses correctly, but doesn't un-focus unless the button is pressed, where it then focuses again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `blur` event listener on the input, not the button. Change:

```
searchBtn.addEventListener('blur', function() {
   ^
```

to:

```
searchInput.addEventListener('blur', function() {
   ^
```

```js
const list = document.querySelector('.output ul');
const searchInput = document.querySelector('.output input');
const searchBtn = document.querySelector('.output button');
const historyDiv = document.querySelector('.output .search');

list.innerHTML = '';

let myHistory = [];

historyDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";

function addToHistory() {
  // we will only allow a term to be entered if the search input isn't empty
  console.log("button click");
  if (searchInput.value !== '') {
    // number 1
    myHistory.push(searchInput.value);
    console.log(`${searchInput.value} added to history`);
    // empty the list so that we don't display duplicate entries
    // the display is regenerated every time a search term is entered.
    list.innerHTML = '';

    // loop through the array, and display all the search terms in the list
    for (let i = 0; i < myHistory.length; i++) {
      itemText = myHistory[i];
      const listItem = document.createElement('li');
      listItem.textContent = itemText;
      list.appendChild(listItem);
    }

    // If the array length is 5 or more, remove the oldest search term
    if (myHistory.length >= 5) {
      // number 2
      myHistory.shift();
    }

    // empty the search input and focus it, ready for the next term to be entered
    searchInput.value = '';
    searchInput.focus();
  }
}


searchBtn.addEventListener('click', addToHistory);
searchInput.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  console.log("Focussed");

  if (myHistory.length > 0) {
    historyDiv.style.visibility = "visible";
  }
});
searchInput.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  console.log("Blurr");
  historyDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
});
```

```html
<div class="output" style="min-height: 150px;">
  <input type="text"><button style="margin-bottom: 3em;">Search</button>
  <br>
  <div class="search">
    <span>Your recent search terms:</span>
    <ul></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```